# Error "HTTP code 405 Method not allowed" when using CURL for a GET request

Tags: php, ajax, curl

I want to fetch response of a GET request by CURL, but get the Error "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed" and no content is returned (except the header).
The following is my code.

```
$url = "http://api.example.com/Q5PLCmwYzho=/7avEU7ptYyummfheg9!0KA==?aqPI=93566&aqIIO=false&aqIP=false&aqSK=0&aqTK=14&aqSO=date&aqCI=0"
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,        //set request type post or get
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
     'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
     'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch',
     //'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
     //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:14189',
     //'Origin: http://www.example.com',
     //'Host: api.example.com',
     //'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true',
    ),
    CURLOPT_COOKIE => 'Cookie:scarab.profile=%2293566%7C1465411024%22; scarab.mayAdd=%5B%7B%22i%22%3A%2293566%22%7D%2C%7B%22i%22%3A%22117313%22%7D%5D; _ceg.s=o8gwtw; _ceg.u=o8gwtw; _gat=1; _dc_gtm_UA-13212406-1=1; DK-Client=CWUU,09b6ab76-f662-48b3-a1e6-f08779519236; __auc=764bbe2e155314db7ac1a950571; scarab.visitor=%22566B1DCD74FCD3A5%22; _ga=GA1.2.412464545.1465411024'
);

$ch      = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
$content = curl_exec( $ch );
$err     = curl_errno( $ch );
$errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
$header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
$header['errno']   = $err; //no error!
$header['errmsg']  = $errmsg; 
$header['content'] = json_decode($content); // no content!
echo $response['http_code']; //output: 405
```

I checked the corresponding ajax request in the webpage and every curl options seems to be set correctly. The details (captured from chrome Dev tools) are shown in the image.
 ![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW8k1.png

What am I missing?? I searched a lot but couldn't solve the problem! I know one of the causes of this error is using an unauthorized request method for curl but the corresponding AJAX call uses GET method and get the result.

What is wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Update: I wrote an AJAX request to fetch the data in local server (localhost) and got this error : **"Cross-Origin Request Blocked"**. It means that I can't make request to a different domain (api.example.com) from localhost. Are there any workarounds or hack to get the response content from that server?

Comment: `'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',` — Why do you have that? You are making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the content type of.

Comment: `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:14189',` — Why do you have that? `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` isn't a request header. It is only a response header.

Comment: `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'` — Ditto

Comment: @Quentin Hi, these options are set in the ajax call (You can see them in request headers section in the image: [link] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/uzVb6.png). I first tried the curl without these options but still get the same error.

Comment: The JavaScript is also wrong then.

Comment: @Questin Ok! I deleted them just keeping 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' and 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch'. Still get the same error (405). What do you think is the cause of problem?

Comment: Try adding curl option `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error in Postman. In my case it was because I was using GET when I should have used POST. Also I was using GET params instead of POST params. Checking the proper method (specified in my java code) and using the "code" button in postman to display the curl CLI helped me.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to send User-Agent in your request.
2. If page that you requested needs any authorization then you need to send cookies with auth data.

Comment: This should be a comment to OP, not an answer, unless you expand on it.

Comment: @marv255 Hi, tnx for your suggestion. I included CURLOPT_USERAGENT and CURLOPT_COOKIE options but the problem exists. :(

Comment: Do you have any possibility to see web server's logs on site that you request with curl?